# while(true) vs socket.accept()

Tags: java, sockets

I read some  tutorial about sockets in Java, and I found that different examples had different explanations on how to use the ServerSocket class.

For example here are two different implementations:

```
 Socket s = serverSocket.accept();
 //using s
```

and

```
while(true)
{
   Socket s = serverSocket.accept();
}
```

What is the difference between these two cases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first accepts only one connections, while the second will continue accepting more connections (each time it reaches `Socket s = serverSocket.accept();`)

Answer (score 2):

From documentation:

> Listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts it. The method blocks until a connection is made.

In the first example, you're working with only one connection, in the second with unlimited connections until you stop them manually (`break`)

Answer (score 2):

The second example keeps `accept`ing connections forever *obviously*.